# How to pass C# datatable as a parameter in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to pass datatable as a parameter from C# code to a stored procedure parameter in SQL Server.

This is my C# code:

```
objCmd = new SqlCommand("usp_UpdateQuantityInWorkOrders", objConn);
objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

var multipleQuantitiesDataTable = ConvertListToDataTable(request.MultipleQuantitiesViewModel.MultipleQuantities);

objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@multipleQuantities", multipleQuantitiesDataTable);
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedWorkOrdersType", request.SelectedWorkOrdersType);
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldProductCode", request.OldProduct.ProductCode);
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewProductCode", request.NewProduct.ProductCode);

SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@affectedRecords", SqlDbType.Int);
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
objCmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

objConn.Open();
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
objConn.Close();

int output = Convert.ToInt32(objCmd.Parameters["@affectedRecords"].Value);
```

This is a snapshot of the `multipleQuantitiesDataTable`:

[image: Datatable during debugging]

Here is the code of my SQL Server stored procedure:

```
create procedure usp_UpdateQuantityInWorkOrders
    @multipleQuantities as MultipleQuantitiesType readonly,
    @SelectedWorkOrdersType nvarchar(100) = null,
    @OldProductCode as nvarchar(50),
    @NewProductCode as nvarchar(50),
    @affectedRecords integer output
as
begin try
    --Commented the complete code for testing purposes
end try
begin catch
    rollback transaction myTran
    declare @Message varchar(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    declare @Severity int = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    declare @State smallint = ERROR_STATE()
    RAISERROR (@Message, @Severity, @State)
end catch
```

`MultipleQuantitiesType` is a ser-defined table-type is defined like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MultipleQuantitiesType AS TABLE
       (
            OldProductCode [varchar(16) NULL,
            OldProductId int NULL,
            OldQuantity int NULL,
            NewProductCode varchar(16) NULL,
            NewProductId int NULL,
            NewQuantity int NULL
       )
```

As soon as I run this program, execution is being aborted with this exception:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_UpdateQuantityInWorkOrders, Line 0
> Operand type clash: table is incompatible with MultipleQuantitiesType

I searched in Google to identify the issue. I got [this article](https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) to find different ways of passing data from .NET client to SQL Server stored procedure, but nothing worked for me.

Gone through [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/468016/identify-cause-of-operand-type-clash-text-is-incom) and some more articles and understood that the columns orders does matter. Hence, I too tried to align the column names accordingly, but no luck.

Can someone help me to identify and fix the issue?

Comment: Did this SP work well inside the sql server?

Comment: @BrandoZhang: Since the ulitmate goal is to make this SP execute from inside C# code, I'm trying for the same and it is not working. The program is aborting with the exception - `Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_UpdateQuantityInWorkOrders, Line 0
Operand type clash: table is incompatible with MultipleQuantitiesType`

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, we need to let our `SqlCommand` object know that we are passing User Defined Table Type as parameter.

In Visual studio, while calling `usp_UpdateQuantityInWorkOrders` stored procedure, add `SqlParameter` like below.

```
SqlParameter prmMultipleQuantities = new SqlParameter();
prmMultipleQuantities.TypeName = "dbo.MultipleQuantitiesType";//UDTT name
prmMultipleQuantities.Value = dtblMultipleQuantities; //DataTable
prmMultipleQuantities.ParameterName = "@multipleQuantities";
objCmd.Parameters.Add(prmMultipleQuantities);
```